# How does a component in a component library reference components in another library?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

Assume I want to create a component library that uses another like *widget*. The convention is to put the (.html|.dart) files together in */components*. The Web UI page discusses importing a component - but it looks like that is in the situation where the imported component is already part of the current project.

From an html file under the /web folder, doing

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/widget/components/accordion.html">
```

works just fine. But, what if I want to use the accordion from a widget in my own component library - what is the way to import. For instance, say I have a *stuff* component library with a *stuff_editor* that needs to use widget's accordion. From the *stuff_editor.html*, the similar link fails on the build step. It seems to be looking for: *"web/packages/stuff/components/packages/widget/components/accordion.html"* and fails as shown:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `package:` url prefix rather than a relative url.

```
<link rel="import" href="package:widget/components/accordion.html">
```

You can do this to include components from another library or from your own library.